# how to add items from listbox to textbox c#

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox

I was doing an ITP project. I needed to add all the items in the listbox to a textbox. The code that i tried using was:

```
tbxReceipt.Text = "The items you purchased are:\r\n\r\n" + lbxItemBought.Items.ToString()
+ "\r\n\r\nYour total price was:" + lblLastCheckout.Text;
```

But when i use the code lbxItemBought.Item.ToString(), it comes up with the error:

System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+ObjectCollection.

I was wondering if there was another way to do it?

thanks

Comment: +1 for showing your attempt and being clear about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You will need to loop over your ListBox collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through listbox.

```
string value = "The items you purchased are:\r\n\r\n";
foreach (var item in lbxItemBought.Items)
{
   value += "," + item.ToString(); 
}

value += "\r\n\r\nYour total price was:" + lblLastCheckout.Text ;
tbxReceipt.Text = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you are doing string manipulation with a loop, use a `StringBuilder`

Now try

```
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
a.Append("The items you purchased are:\r\n\r\n");
foreach (var item in lbxItemBought.Items)
{
    a.Append(item.ToString());
}
a.Append("\r\nYour total price was:");
a.Append(lblLastCheckout.Text);
tbxReceipt.Text = a.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

That message is no error, it is just the string representation of the `Items`-property of your listbox.

When you want to get a concatenation of the item names (for example), you must iterate over the `Items`-collection, cast the single elements to the things you put into it and then concatenate a display string. For example, if the type of your items is `SomeItem` and it has a property like `Name`, you can use LINQ like this:

```
var itemNames = string.Join(", ", lbxItemBought.Items
                                               .Cast<SomeItem>()
                                               .Select(item => item.Name));
tbxReceipt.Text = "The items you purchased are:\r\n\r\n" + itemNames + "\r\n\r\nYour total price was:" + lblLastCheckout.Text;
```

Comment: sorry for my low knowledge, but what is <SomeItem>, because when i put it in my code an error shows up saying " the type or namespace name 'SomeItem' could not be found. what do i do?

Comment: It is the type of the item you put into the listbox. If these are only strings, use `string` instead of `SomeItem`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = string.Empty;

foreach(var item in lbxItemBought.Items)
    result + = item.ToString()+Environment.NewLine;

txtReceipt.Text = result;
```